# C++ Gmock - test function which uses shared_ptr <FactoryClass>

Tags: c++, factory, factory-pattern, googlemock

I am new to gtest/gmock and trying to test a simple function in c++ which has a two pointers 'm_propBsh_p' and 'm_eBsh_p'; these pointers becomes valid after some factory-creations, however i do not want to get involve in factory classes complexities and callbacks. 
Following is the function definition that i want to write test for:

```
    std::string Foo::toString(const std::string &indent) const
    {
    ....

    std::string str =
      (m_propBsh_p != nullptr) ? m_propBsh_p -> toString("P-BSH: ") : "-";
    str +=
      (m_eBsh_p != nullptr) ? m_eBsh_p -> toString("E-BSH: ") : "-";

    return str;
  }
```

Since I am just interested in testing this particular toString function therefore I just want to have valid pointers for 'm_propBsh_p' and 'm_eBsh_p'. I am aiming/trying for something like following:

```
  //Assuming to have mocked class for pointers
  std::shared_ptr<MockedBshClass> m_mockEBsh_p;
  std::shared_ptr<MockedBshClass> m_mockPropBsh_p;

  TEST_F(FooTest, toStringBshInfoPass)
  {
    std::string eBshAndpBshStr = "eBshAndpBshStr";

    ON_CALL(*m_mockPropBsh_p, toString(_)).WillByDefault(Return(eBshAndpBshStr));
    ON_CALL(*m_mockEBsh_p, toString(_)).WillByDefault(Return(eBshAndpBshStr ));
    //EXPECT_CALL((*m_mockPropBsh_p), toString(_)).Times(1);
    //EXPECT_CALL((*m_mockEBsh_p), toString(_)).Times(1);

    //Call mock or some fake function which makes m_propBsh_p & m_eBsh_p valid.
    foo->makePtrValidAgain(); //however this is a complex function which bring more callbacks and complexity and i do not want to call, instead i want to have some fake/mocked function which just gives me valid pointers

    EXPECT_THAT(foo->toString(""),HasSubstr(eBshAndpBshStr+eBshAndpBshStr));
  }
```

Following is bit background of the Foo class and pointers:

```
   Class Foo : fooParent..
   {
   ...
    void makePtrValidAgain();
    std::string toString();
    ..
    typedef std::shared_ptr<BshClass> m_propBsh_p;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<BshClass> m_eBsh_p; 
   ...
   }; 

   void Foo::makePtrValidAgain()
   {
   ...
   auto someFactory = m_dependencyContainer->get<bssh::SomeFactory>();
   assert(someFactory);

   auto nextTask = [this](std::uint32_t dummy){runAfterFoo();};

   m_propBsh_p = someFactory->create(callback, nextTask);
   m_propBsh_p->execute();
   ...
   //and same happens with m_eBsh_p

   return;       
   }
```

I am not sure, what is a best way to avoid complexity for test of such simple function using gmock/gtest, purpose for me is to have valid pointers as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems your `ON_CALL`s are incorrect. You mock the `BshClass`, so you want to create expectations on methods of `BshClass` (and `toString()` isn't one). You should mock for example

```
ON_CALL(*m_mockEBsh_p, execute())/*stuff to do*/;
```

To answer your question:

1. If the factory is used in Foo constructor already (you passed your mock pointers to `m_propBsh_p` and `m_eBsh_p`), then you could just use `std::shared_ptr` functionality to control if they point to something or not (e.g. via `reset()`).
2. Otherwise, it seems a good idea to extract factory method from `makePtrValidAgain()` - this function already has more than one responsibility, it creates pointers and calls methods on them.

I'd propose something like:

```
   Class Foo : fooParent..
   {
   ...
    void makePtrValidAgain();
    std::string toString();
    ..
    private:
    void resetPointers();
    typedef std::shared_ptr<BshClass> m_propBsh_p;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<BshClass> m_eBsh_p; 
   ...
   }; 

   void Foo::makePtrValidAgain()
   {
   ...
   resetPointers(); //if needed
   m_propBsh_p->execute();
   ...
   //and same happens with m_eBsh_p
   }

   void resetPointers()
   {
   auto someFactory = m_dependencyContainer->get<bssh::SomeFactory>();
   assert(someFactory);

   auto nextTask = [this](std::uint32_t dummy){runAfterFoo();};

   m_propBsh_p = someFactory->create(callback, nextTask);
   //also with the other pointer
   //or better pass the pointer to reset as argument if possible
   }
```

and call `resetPointers()` in Foo constructor if possible. Or make it public and call it from UT. This way the problem falls down to first option with `m_propBsh_p` and `m_eBsh_p` being set and you have access to them from UT via your mock pointers.